# Linux tracing/trace_pipe file not readable (debugfs)

Tags: linux, bash, file, ubuntu, ebpf

I have BPF program that writes into trace_pipe file, and even though the program executes correctly, I cannot read data from this file.

Whenever I try to `cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_pipe`, the process gets stuck, and nothing is shown as output.

[image]

I have manually mounted the debugfs by running: `mount -t debugfs none /sys/kernel/debug`
and when I try to cat, tail, vi, or somehow read the content of this file, the result is the same.

The "trace_pipe" file is not readable even right after I mount the debugfs, so I don't believe this is related to my BPF code execution.

This file is simply not readable, and I want to understand what should I do to be able to read it.

I can confirm the debugfs is properly mounted, and the file does exist:

[image]

[image]

I appreciate any tips on how should I read this file.

Comment: It's expected that it blocks on `trace_pipe`. It just means nothing is sent to the pipe. Could you share your BPF program and the program to load it?

Comment: This is the BPF program: https://github.com/libbpf/libbpf-bootstrap/blob/master/examples/c/minimal.bpf.c

This is the program to load it: https://github.com/libbpf/libbpf-bootstrap/blob/master/examples/c/minimal.c

They both execute correctly. I'm running ./minimal, and then I stop it to run the cat command. Should I try something different?

Comment: Try to run ./minimal and the cat command at the same time.

Comment: I have tried before to run ./minimal, and while the BPF program is running, I run the cat command on another terminal window, but it didn't work: I got the same result.

Comment: Your eBPF program has `if (pid != my_pid) return 0;`, with `int my_pid = 0;`, before the call to `bpf_printk()`. Won't this make your program exit all the time before it gets a chance to print anything to the trace pipe?

Comment: That was exactly the issue @Qeole, after removing the if statement, the BPF program perfectly print the output and the file is readable. Thanks to you, and also @pchaino!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was simply a mistake in your eBPF program. From your link:

```c
int my_pid = 0;

SEC("tp/syscalls/sys_enter_write")
int handle_tp(void *ctx)
{
    int pid = bpf_get_current_pid_tgid() >> 32;

    if (pid != my_pid)
        return 0;

    bpf_printk("BPF triggered from PID %d.\n", pid);

    return 0;
}
```

Having `if (pid != my_pid) return 0;`, with `my_pid = 0`, means you exit each time the PID you collect is non-0 - which is pretty much *all the time*. So your program exits early and you don't get a chance to execute the call to `bpf_printk()` and send data to the trace pipe.